# Initialising a public module-level variable

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA module has multiple subroutines. In most of them I calculate the last non-empty row so as to avoid loading unneeded cells.

Once the code checks which is the last non-empty cell of the second worksheet in the current workbook for the first time, the value of the variable stays constant throughout the changes done to the worksheet with the subroutines. So I am trying to declare and initialise it only once, instead of every time for each subroutine.

The declaration works:

```
Option Explicit

Public lastrow As Long

Public Sub CleanOrderNumbers()

 With Worksheets(2)
 
        Dim range As range
           
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set range = .range("A2:A" & lastrow)
        range.Replace What:="#", Replacement:="OrdNo"

 End With

End Sub
```

However I'd like to initialise the variable only once as well and avoid the repeating `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

I've tried using a function or a sub to take care of the initialisation.

```
Option Explicit

Public lastrow As Long

Public Function myrow()

lastrow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'alternatively as a constant?
'Const lastrow As Integer = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Function

Public Sub CleanOrderNumbers()

 With Worksheets(2)
 
        Dim range   As range
           
        Set range = .range("A2:A" & lastrow)
        range.Replace What:="#", Replacement:="OrdNo"

End With

End Sub
```

To no avail. Am I missing something in the syntax? Or is this supposed to be done in an entirely different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are calling `myrow()`?

Call `myrow()` or set the variable directly when the workbook opens by adding an event handler in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    lastrow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'or
    myrow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition as Const will not work in VBA as they cannot be initialized at runtime, a Const needs to be defined at compile time.

To avoid that the `End`-command is executed over and over again, you could simply check if the value is already set

```
If lastrow = 0 Then lastrow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Having lastrow defined as global would mean that this statement will be put everywhere in the code, so the idea to have a function instead is good. If I where you, I would name the function itself `lastrow` and rename the variable - now the rest of the code doesn't need to be changed at all.

```
Dim myLastRow as Long

Public Function lastrow()
    If myLastRow  = 0 Then 
        myLastRow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    lastrow = myLastRow 
End Function
```

Now that would still leave `myLastRow` as global variable. If you want to avoid that (and force the code to exclusively use the function), declare it as `Static` local variable.

```
Public Function lastrow()
    Static myLastRow as Long 
    If myLastRow = 0 Then 
        myLastRow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    lastrow = myLastRow 
End Function
```